# .NET Microservices with CQRS handling dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, microservices

Hello I would like you to ask for advise from people that already worked with Microservices on bigger scale thane TODO example.

Let me explain base thoughts about architecture. I want to create system in Microservice architecture with CQRS. I imagine that Microservice A will Handle bunch of Commands and Events but other Microservice can listen on that Event too. So in general somehow I have to separate Event contract between those two Microservices. To get better overview see simple diagram:

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oigyR.jpg)

*i'm leave here all bus stuff and handlers and logic inside, I hope it's obvious. I want to focus on contracts only*

My idea on the beginnig was to put code with Microservice A with all Events for this domain in one solution, but Events will be placed in separate library that will be exposed as nuget. Then this nuget will be consumed by Microservice B which will implement own Handlers based on Contract.

Microservice A solution:

- MicroserviceCode (Commands and Handlers with business logic etc)
- DomainContract (Events that can be shared between many services but
  are connected to current solution domain)

MicroserviceCode has project dependency to own DomainContract and other DomainContract nugets

But then I realized that when Microservices will grow and grow and more 
dependencies will come it can start nuget hell and cause dependencies issues because of wrong nuget packages etc.

I also thought about sharing contract as a Rest API in Json format and eliminate nuget versioning.

I would like to discuss about any tips how to avoid hell dependencies between Microservices.

Or maybe you worked with the approach that I describe and it's not that bad than I think?:)

Comment: This is a great question, but unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you know any site where I can discuss such a things?

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend you is to **Share** Data Contract and Event contract through a Project Reference and have all of your project into one solution, that way the compiler will tell you instantly where you need to fix things if you change a Contract.
Of course the **down side** of this is that you need to deploy all services every time, since if going to be hard to know which service uses a specific Contract when you check in.

I like the Idea of having a nuget package and Repository/Service, but imagen if you decide to change a Contract, you have to know **in advance** which Services consume that Contract, check out the code and update nuget package and check in the code, you need to repeat for all Microservices that consume that changed Contract.

I have seen both solutions in production, but I think that First solution is more bullet proof since you don’t need to think of if any service that is running in any environments has old Data Contract.

**Heads up**
The only thing that you should share between Services in Contracts.